# Why cypress loads login page again instead of home page?

Tags: cypress

I wrote a cypress script to log in to the application ( enter the user id, password and click the log-in button), and expecting to load the home page. Cypress enters the user id, password and clicks the button but, loads the login page again instead of the home page.
Below is my script to login:
`

```
cy.visit('https://digitalxq1.com/sis/basic?accountNumber=123456');
cy.enterText(txtUserID, userid);
cy.enterText(txtPwd, 121212);
cy.clickElement(btnPwd);
```

Has anyone faced a similar issue? And, Does anyone knows the solution? Please assist.

Comment: can u provide screenshot of cypress runner left panel

Comment: How does your app determine whether to show login or home page? My initial guess is that the cookies (or something similar) set when actually logging in are clear on each test execution.

Answer (score 0):

The nature of the application forced me to log in first without account no- " cy.visit('https://digitalxq1.com/sis/basic'"   and reload the app with account number after that - "cy.visit('https://digitalxq1.com/sis/basic?accountNumber=123456')" ).

I made mistake of doing the refresh immediately after clicking on login button as below:

```
cy.visit('https://digitalxq1.com/sis/basic');
cy.enterText(txtUserID, userid);
cy.enterText(txtPwd, 121212);
cy.clickElement(btnPwd);
cy.visit('https://digitalxq1.com/sis/basic?accountNumber=123456'
```

Somehow cypress unable to respond to the refresh and loaded the login page again. As a solution, I did validate whether the app is loaded or not after clicking login button. Then proceeded with refresh  as below:

```
cy.visit('https://digitalxq1.com/sis/basic');
cy.enterText(txtUserID, userid);
cy.enterText(txtPwd, 121212);
cy.clickElement(btnPwd);
cy.get(#testElement). should('have.length',2);
cy.visit('https://digitalxq1.com/sis/basic?accountNumber=123456'
```

This approach resolved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try this `cy.reload();` this will work.

If you want to reload the page with cache then try this `cy.reload(true)`